# Experiment with eels

Tags: ancova

I have carried out an experiment to study the physical effect of the insertion of a pit tag in the dorsal body of the eel. Thus I selected at random 49 eels and insert a small pit-tag (8.0 mm long x 2.1 mm diameter), in another group of 51 I inserted big pit (12 mm long x 2.1 mm diam) and left a third group of 82 specimens with no pit. I took length and weight every month along 8 months. My null hypothesis is that pit (either big or small) does no affect the physical condition of the individual.
Because I do not think that two variables highly related as length and weight can be analysed by separate, I carried out an ANCOVA, using weight as response variable, length as covariate and months (8 levels) and pit (three levels) as factors in R:

`model<-log (weight)~month*pit*log(length)`

My questions are

1. Am I correct not to analyse length or weight separately?;
2. Is  the ANCOVA the correct analysis to study such effect? Another possibility could be to apply the same analysis only to the survivors of the last month of the experiment;
3. I have also the growth rate (differences in mean weight/length between two consecutives months of the three groups). How I can compare these growth rates? I have carried out a Kruskal-Wallis analysis but I am not sure if this is the best analysis to detect possible differences between growth rates.

Comment: Not really answering any of your questions: With humans it's common to deal with the height/weight correlation by combining them as BMI (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_mass_index); maybe that works just as well for eels?

Comment: Yes! thank you! we use a similar indexes, among other I use the residual condition (rK) which uses the residuals of the length-weight relationship as a measurement of the fish fitness. A factorial Anova (rK~date*pit) did not show significant differences between the three groups.